# newrelic_rpm: undefined method `before_save' for #<Class:0x00000004a28b28>

Tags: heroku, rake, newrelic

Since I've updated newrelic_rpm gem from 3.5.8.72 to 3.6.1.88 on my Heroku app I've noticed newrelic is loading on my rake task giving me strange errors:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `before_save' for #<Class:0x00000003d2f908>
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:90:in `<class:Session>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:79:in `<class:SessionStore>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:53:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:138:in `session_store'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:273:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `tap'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `default_middleware_stack'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `app'
...
```

I know the problem comes from newrelic_rpm for sure, so I wonder how can I disable it on rake tasks somehow.

I tried with https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/forcing-the-ruby-agent-to-start setting an ENV var, but it will disable newrelic for the webapp too. Is there a way to set the ENV var for all my rake task but only on rake and not in the webserver?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution depends on how your run your rake tasks. For example if you are running this from a cronjob then you can prepend `NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false` to the cron entry for your rake task.

Otherwise if you are running your rake tasks by hand, you should add the following to your newrelic.yml file.

`autostart.blacklisted_executables: rake`

This will prevent the agent from starting up in any instance where the executable is called rake. Note that this can also be a comma separated list if you have other executables that you wish to prevent New Relic from starting up in.

Comment: Thanks so much Steven. I'm using cronjobs and I was looking to avoid adding the NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false to every single entry (it could be tricky in the future). So the line for the file newrelic.yml is perfect!